# R: plotly: How to customize the scope on the map plots?

Tags: r, dictionary, plotly

I'm trying to use the plotly package to create visualizations on the data of Tamil Nadu Districts in India.

I'm able to create such as the one below data from [here](https://tuxworld.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/latitiude-longitude-altitude-for-all-over-india-cities/):
[image: Districts of Tamil Nadu Altitude]
code for it below

```
library(plotly)
df <- tamil_nadu__.india_._lat.long.alt 
df$hover <- paste(df$name, "Altitude", df$Altitude_in_ft, "Altitude in Feet")

df$q <- with(df, cut(Altitude_in_ft, quantile(Altitude_in_ft)))
levels(df$q) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"), "Quantile")
df$q <- as.ordered(df$q)

g <- list(
  scope = "asia",
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  subunitwidth = 1,
  countrywidth = 1,
  subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("white")
)

plot_ly(df, lon = Lon, lat = Lat, text = hover,color = q, type = 'scattergeo') %>%
  layout(geo = g)
`
```

However, I don't have district/city or state outlines available. Plotly provides this only for USA.

I do have access to Shape files from http://www.gadm.org/country

Is it possible to import a shape file and use map plots from plotly?

Comment: you should provide the code you used to produce that map.

Comment: a good alternative to plotly would be to use leaflet

Answer (score 2):

to follow-up with my comment, here is an alternative (I don't know if it's possible with plotly) that could give you want you want. I downloaded the shapefile from your link, set the projection and plot. I don't have access to your dataset but your would only need to add addCircles() or addMarkerCircles() to the expression below.

```
library(maptools)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

IND_adm1 <- readShapeSpatial("pathtoyour/IND_adm1.shp")
proj4string(IND_adm1) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")

str(IND_adm1@data)
factpal <- colorFactor(topo.colors(36), IND_adm1$NAME_1)

leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>% 
addPolygons(data=IND_adm1, color= ~factpal(NAME_1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MLavoie. Is there a way to make such a plot interactive and maybe plot over it. For example, plot populations over such a map and make it interactive.

Comment: yes, like I said it my answer you could use addCircles() (to add points) at the end of the code I showed you. You did not provide your dataset in your example so I could not add those points.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about incorporating leaflet? For example, this code will give you a map of the region:

```
install.packages("leaflet")
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
    setView(lng = 78, lat = 10.5, zoom = 6)
```

And then you can use either `addPolygons()` or `addPolylines()` to incorporate the data from gadm.org., with the argument `data`, e.g.:

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
    setView(lng = 78, lat = 10.5, zoom = 6)  %>% 
    addPolylines(data = YOUR_DATA, color = "blue", weight = 3)
```